# JHipster deploy on glassfish 4 error

Tags: java, spring-boot, glassfish, jhipster

I have an application based on JHipster and I am trying to deploy on GlassFish (the war) but I always get the error:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app
>   [LyncisVisualizadorChip] :
>   sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy. Please see
>   server.log for more details.

I researched a lot and found similar questions: 
 
[Exception deploying JHipster app to Glassfish 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767537/exception-deploying-jhipster-app-to-glassfish-4-1)

[Spring Boot on Glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28737018/spring-boot-on-glassfish)

[Spring Boot App does not deploy on Glassfish 4.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431579/spring-boot-app-does-not-deploy-on-glassfish-4-1)

But none of these answers help me. Is there an alternative?

Full Stack:

```
> [2017-08-16T13:06:11.623-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] []
> [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=46
> _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1502899571623] [levelValue: 900] [[   AS-DEPLOYMENT-00011
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/crsh/plugin/PluginLifeCycle   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:585)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crsh.plugin.PluginLifeCycle     at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>   ... 101 more ]]
> 
> [2017-08-16T13:06:12.107-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] []
> [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.dol] [tid: _ThreadID=46
> _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1502899572107] [levelValue: 900] [[   AS-DEPLOYMENT-00011
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/crsh/plugin/PluginLifeCycle   at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)     at
> java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)   at
> java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1220)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.annotation.impl.ModuleScanner.getElements(ModuleScanner.java:297)
>   at
> org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:132)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:626)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:462)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:446)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:338)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.deployment.archivist.WebArchivist.postAnnotationProcess(WebArchivist.java:91)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:420)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:396)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:271)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:280)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:241)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:161)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.processDOL(DolProvider.java:203)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:227)
>   at
> org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:96)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:881)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:821)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:377)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
>   at
> org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
> javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)    at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:253)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:275)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:133)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>   at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:151)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:171)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:152)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:104)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:387)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:331)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:103)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:271)
>   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)  at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)     at
> org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:254)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
>   at
> org.glassfish.jersey.grizzly2.httpserver.GrizzlyHttpContainer.service(GrizzlyHttpContainer.java:365)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter$2.service(RestAdapter.java:316)
>   at
> org.glassfish.admin.rest.adapter.RestAdapter.service(RestAdapter.java:179)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>   at
> com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.portunif.PUFilter.handleRead(PUFilter.java:231)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
>   at
> org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.crsh.plugin.PluginLifeCycle     at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1783)
>   at
> org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
>   ... 102 more ]]
> 
> [2017-08-16T13:06:12.304-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [global]
> [tid: _ThreadID=46 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis:
> 1502899572304] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Class [
> org/springframework/hateoas/ResourceSupport ] not found. Error while
> loading [ class
> org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointWebMvcHypermediaManagementContextConfiguration$ActuatorEndpointLinksAdvice
> ]]]
> 
> [2017-08-16T13:06:12.397-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] []
> [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=46
> _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1502899572397] [levelValue: 800] [[   visiting unvisited references]]
> 
> [2017-08-16T13:06:12.513-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] []
> [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46
> _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1502899572513] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception while deploying the app
> [LyncisVisualizadorChip]]]
> 
> [2017-08-16T13:06:12.514-0300] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE]
> [NCLS-CORE-00026] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=46
> _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1502899572514] [levelValue: 1000] [[   Exception during lifecycle processing
> java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
> sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(AnnotationParser.java:724)
>   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(AnnotationParser.java:531)
>   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:355)
>   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(AnnotationParser.java:286)
>   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:120)
>   at
> sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:72)
>   at java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Class.java:3521)    at
> java.lang.Class.annotationData(Class.java:3510)   at
> java.lang.Class.getAnnotations(Class.java:3446)   at
> org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:285)
>   at
> org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:195)
```

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Included.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1355 with similar stack trace, it seems there is a related blocking issue that has been fixed in Spring Boot 2.0, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8669 but JHipster will wait for final release before upgrading. So either you try by yourself to upgrade spring boot in your app or you forget about Glassfish.

Comment: There is no way to update spring on jhipster, doing this will change much of the project. I can't forget about Glassfish too.

Comment: I don't know your constraints but maybe Spring Boot and JHipster are not for a good fit for you and you should move to something else. As a last attempt to help you, you could also stay in spring boot 1.x, fork it and backport the 2.0 fix https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/d46591f141bf8edf7944544a26f419bbd8c50549 which is quite limited.